# Why built-in types and classes are threated differently when not used?

Tags: c++, gcc, warnings, unused-variables

Why does this code leads to 2 different warnings?

```
class Abc
{
public:
    Abc() = default;
    Abc(Abc const&) = default;
};

int main()
{
    int val1{int()};
    Abc val2{Abc()};
}
```

Compilation output:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:10:9: warning: unused variable 'val1' [-Wunused-variable]
     int val1{int()};
         ^~~~
main.cpp:11:9: warning: variable 'val2' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     Abc val2{Abc()};
         ^~~~
```

[Live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac7d546f13ea7d8e)

Comment: It produces the same warning for me... (unused variable). I guess it depends on the compiler

Comment: Is there a place where you easily try this on clang and see the output? In my experience gcc is not as robust in the errors. I suspect that in the first case what happens is that you are just declaring a variable to be int (What does the int fucntion do? Does it give it a random value?) In the second case maybe you have a proper object instantiation so the variable is detected as set?

Comment: @XapaJIaMnu `T()` yelds to default initialization of type (So defaults for built-ins, `T::T()` for classes). So `int()` yields to `0`.

Comment: @BlackMoses unfortunately I'm at work at the moment with rather outdated GCC and no clang. I'll play around with some up2date tools tonight and get back to you. Thanks for the clarification on the default initializations. I think it might just be a compiler oversight though. What exactly causes it would probably require viewing some assembly.

Answer (score 0):

The warnings are self explanatory. The code compiles and runs as you expect, but the compiler is advising you to optimize your code by removing variables that have no use in your program (declaring a variable that does not apear later in the program).

Comment: I know that, but why `int` doesn't generate `[-Wunused-but-set-variable]` warning?